# Is there a way to serialize multiple objects in Django?

Tags: python, json, django

In a Django Project I would like to implement a simple chat-box.

**Version**

Django version 3.0.8

**Models.py**

```
class DirectMessageClass(models.Model):  
sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='from_this')
receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='to_this')
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def serialize(self):
    return {
        "id": self.id,
        "sender": self.sender.username,
        "sendername":self.sender.profile.firstname,
        "senderimage":self.sender.profile.image.url,
        "receiver": self.receiver.username,
        "content": self.content,
        "timestamp":self.timestamp.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"), # to format date
        "read":self.read,
    }
```

**Views.py**

```
def loadbox(request):
user = request.user 
# Return messages in reverse chronologial order
messages = DirectMessageClass.objects.filter(receiver=user).order_by("-timestamp").all()
return JsonResponse([message.serialize() for message in messages], safe=False)
```

I successfully get messages and turn it into a JSON object in the /loadbox path with this method. Later on, I fetch this data to display messages and it works.

**Example of my /loadbox path**

```
[{"id": 1, "sender": "ekvatorcizgisi", "sendername": "Asli", 
  "receiver": "bilge", "content": "hi", "timestamp": "09/02/2020, 08:22:26", "read": true}]
```

However, because I want it to display as a dialog. I need to add also the reply messages in this JSON object.

**In views.py I try**

```
def loadbox(request):
user = request.user 
# Return messages in reverse chronologial order
messages = DirectMessageClass.objects.filter(receiver=user).order_by("-timestamp").all()
# return replies sent by the current user
replies = DirectMessageClass.objects.filter(sender=user).order_by("-timestamp").all()
return JsonResponse([message.serialize() for message in messages], safe=False)
```

I am not sure how to return multiple Json response in the /loadbox path

```
return JsonResponse([message.serialize() for message in messages,reply.serialize() for reply in replies], safe=False)
```

gives syntax error obviously, (SyntaxError: invalid syntax) I also tried the put it all in a list but couldn't make it work.

***My ideal output is***

```
 [messages: {"id": 1, "sender": "ekvatorcizgisi", "sendername": "Asli", 
  "receiver": "bilge", "content": "hi", "timestamp": "09/02/2020, 08:22:26", "read": true}
  replies:{"id": 3, "sender": "bilged", "sendername": "bilge", 
  "receiver": "Asli", "content": "hi there", "timestamp": "09/02/2020, 08:22:26", "read": false}]
```

Maybe I would do another path for reply messages to solve this problem, but I wonder is there any better way to do this?

Comment: *"gives syntax error"* seems fine to me, What error you have got?\

Comment: return JsonResponse([message.serialize() for message in messages,reply.serialize() for reply in replies], safe=False)
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ***list up-packing*** technique

```
def loadbox(request):
    # rest of your code
    return JsonResponse(
        [
            *[message.serialize() for message in messages],
            *[reply.serialize() for reply in replies]
        ],
        safe=False
    )
```

**Simple demonstration:**

```
In [1]: foo = [1,2,3]                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [2]: bar = [5,6,7]                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [3]: foo_bar = [*foo,*bar]                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [4]: foo_bar                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```